# Marking subsequent month for the duration of the dates more than a month

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2016

I have below two tables:

1. orders - will store the duration with start date and end date
2. calendar - dimension table with all the dates.

   ```
       create table #orders
       (
           order_id int identity(1,1) primary key
           ,start_date date
           ,end_date date
       )

       insert into #orders
       (
           start_date
           ,end_date
       )values('2018-01-05','2019-02-04'),('2018-03-15','2019-07-14')  

       create table #calendar_dates
       (
           [date] date
       )

       ;WITH calendar
           AS (SELECT dates = CONVERT(date, '2018-01-01' )
               UNION ALL
               SELECT dates = Dateadd(DAY, 1, dates)
               FROM   calendar
               WHERE  dates < ='2020-12-31' 
               )
       insert into #calendar_dates
       (
           date
       )  
       select 
           c.dates  
       from
           calendar c
           OPTION( MAXRECURSION 0)


       select * from #orders

       select * from #calendar_dates
   ```

For each order I need to mask an extra column with an indicator saying the month completed, if the calendar dates comes across that date.

Eg: The output should look like below:

```
        calendar_date      order_id     start_date      end_date        is_month
        -------------------------------------------------------------------------
        2018-01-01             1        2018-01-01      2019-02-04        1
        2018-01-02             1        2018-01-01      2019-02-04        0
        2018-01-03             1        2018-01-01      2019-02-04        0
        .
        .
        .
        .
        .
        .
        .
        2018-02-01             1        2018-01-01      2019-02-04        1
        .
        .
        2018-03-01             1        2018-01-01      2019-02-04        1
        .
        .
        2018-04-01             1        2018-01-01      2019-02-04        1
        .
        .
        2018-05-01             1        2018-01-01      2019-02-04        1
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you need to mark the start of each month, for each order?

```
SELECT
    T.date,
    O.order_id,
    O.start_date,
    O.end_date,
    is_month = CASE WHEN DATEPART(DAY, T.date) = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
FROM
    #calendar_dates AS T
    INNER JOIN #orders AS O ON T.date BETWEEN O.start_date AND O.end_date
ORDER BY
    O.order_id,
    T.date
```